# In VSCode, how to render shell commands in markdown (not under preview mode)

Tags: shell, visual-studio-code, syntax-highlighting

I can't make the raw linux commands to have syntax highlight like the following:

```sh
rm -rf FILE
```

As a contrary, some specific keys would have effects, like the following:

```sh
if [[ -f FILE ]]
then rm -rf FILE;
fi
```

They are rendered as the following:

[image]

What I expected to is that ont only highlight `if | then |fi`, but also highlight `rm / find / sed...`.

Am I expecting too much?

Comment: `rm`, `find` are not shell keywords, they are executables found on your path